# Meteor : subscribe to collection subset & collection total count

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Here is my issue :

I'm subscribing to a subset of a Collection for "infinite pagination" in iron-router (like the Discover Meteor example) :

```
ApplicationsListController = RouteController.extend({
   template: 'applicationsList',
   increment: 10,
   limit: function(){
       return parseInt(this.params.applicationsLimit) || this.increment;
   },
   findOptions: function(){
       return {sort: {name: 1}, limit: this.limit()};
   },
   subscriptions: function(){
     this.applicationsSub = Meteor.subscribe('applications', this.findOptions()) ;
   },
   applications: function(){
     return Applications.find({}, this.findOptions());  
   },
   data: function(){
       var hasMore = this.applications().fetch().length === this.limit();
       var nextPath = this.route.path({applicationsLimit: this.limit() + this.increment});
       return {
         applications: this.applications(),
         ready: this.applicationsSub.ready,
         nextPath: hasMore ? nextPath : null
       };
   }
});

//(...)

this.route('applicationsList', {
       path: '/applications/:applicationsLimit?',
       controller: ApplicationsListController
});
```

I'm publishing it well, no problem there. But, on the same page, I also need the total count of the entire collection (not only the subset). I publish it like that :

```
Meteor.publish('applications', function(options){
   return Applications.find({}, options);
});

Meteor.publish('applicationsCount', function(){
    return Applications.find().count();
});
```

But there is something I guess I did not understand. I need to use the total count in my template, but I just can't see how to subscribe to "just a number", without creating a new collection (which I don't want to do).

I've seen the 'counts-for-room' example on Meteor Doc, but it seems that it is far from what I need (I don't have room with message in it, I just need to count my applications without getting them all on client).

Thanks a lot, I hope I was clean enough.
Have a great day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thanks to Ethann I made it work.**

First I installed the [publish-counts package](https://github.com/percolatestudio/publish-counts)

```
$ meteor add tmeasday:publish-counts
```

As Ethann said, I published the count on my `server\publications.js`

```
Meteor.publish('applicationsCount', function() {
  Counts.publish(this, 'applicationsCount', Applications.find());
});
```

And I updated my `iron-router` Controller like that :

```
ApplicationsListController = RouteController.extend({
   template: 'applicationsList',
   increment: 10,

   (...)

   subscriptions: function(){
     this.applicationsSub = Meteor.subscribe('applications', this.findOptions()) ;
     this.applicationsCount = Meteor.subscribe('applicationsCount');
   },

   (...)

   data: function(){
       var hasMore = this.applications().fetch().length === this.limit();
       var nextPath = this.route.path({applicationsLimit: this.limit() + this.increment});
       Counts.get('applicationsCount');
       return {
         applications: this.applications(),
         ready: this.applicationsSub.ready,
         nextPath: hasMore ? nextPath : null
       };
   }
});
```

To finally call the count in my template:

```
<span> There is a Total of {{getPublishedCount 'applicationsCount'}} Applications</span>
```

Thanks a lot. Hope it will help some people around here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the Count of the collection.

Try with the [publish-counts package](https://github.com/percolatestudio/publish-counts).

```
$ meteor add tmeasday:publish-counts
```

So this how your code should looks alike.

```
 //server.js
Meteor.publish('applicationsCount', function() {
  Counts.publish(this, 'applicationsCount', Applications.find());
});
```

on the lib folder.

```
if(Meteor.isClient){
   Meteor.subscribe('applicationsCount')
   Counts.get('applicationsCount');
 }
```

Now look that Counts.get works like a helper, so you can use it on the template like this.

```
<span> There is a Total of {{getPublishedCount 'applicationsCount'}} Applications</span>
```

Comment: @Ethann I actually wonder where do I put the `Meteor.subscribe('applicationsCount')` and `Counts.get('applicationsCounts')` in the RouteController I wrote in my question ? :O

Comment: thats on the client side, like any other subscription, create a new folder and name it /lib to ensure that the the first meteor loads its that subscription

Comment: Actually, using iron-router, my subscriptions are in `lib\route.js` as shown above, just don't get where exactly in this case

Comment: put at the very top just put inside a `if(Meteor.isClient){}`

Comment: I use `project\client`,`project\lib`,`project\server`,... I don't have any `if(Meteor.isClient){}`. It's automatic due to my folders. Each subscription is in `lib\route.js`, I read (Discover Meteor) this is best practice :O

Comment: yes inside the `lib/routes.js` put that code, im not sure if `Counts.get('applicationsCount');` runs on both server/client thats why i tell you tu use `if(Meteor.isClient)`

Comment: I made it work! Thank you! :) Gonna post the result.